# Display array values based on user input in Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, input, output

I have a text file feeding my arrays. I have imported them using csv. I have multiple arrays, storing data such as a persons name, address, email etc. I am trying to print out the value of the individual array based on user input.

```
elif option==3:
        print("Which report would you like to run?")
        time.sleep(1)
        reportmenu()
        while True:
            choice=int(input(" "))
            if choice ==1:
                city_input=raw_input("Please enter a city which you would like to display all students from")
                for row in City:
                    if city_input in City:
                        cityindex=City.index(city_input)
                        print("{} {} {} {} {} {} {}".format(ID[cityindex],Surname[cityindex],FirstName[cityindex],City[cityindex],Phone_Number[cityindex],Gender[cityindex],Email[cityindex]))
```

So if the user enters the name of the city, and it appears in the City array, the program can print out the other relevant information relating to the user stored in the other arrays. I have tried indexing based on user input, but this doesn't work, and I get the following output:

```
001,Surname1,Shaun,18/09/86,Sheffield,012345,Male,shaun@shaun.com
001,Surname1,Shaun,18/09/86,Sheffield,012345,Male,shaun@shaun.com
001,Surname1,Shaun,18/09/86,Sheffield,012345,Male,shaun@shaun.com
001,Surname1,Shaun,18/09/86,Sheffield,012345,Male,shaun@shaun.com
```

In my text file (converted to csv) I have the following data (so far):

```
001,Surname1,Shaun,18/09/86,Sheffield,012345,Male,shaun@shaun.com
002,Surname2,Ifty,01/01/01,Rotherham,0123456,Male,Ifty@ifty.com
003,Surname3,Dawn,01/01/01,Doncaster,0123456,Female,Dawn@Dawn.com
004,Surname4,Bryan,01/01/01,Sheffield,012345,Male,Bryan@deaf.com
```

So if the user types in 'Sheffield', it should display the information for Shaun and Bryan.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "but this doesn't work" - What happens instead?

Comment: So the output I get when I run this and enter 'Sheffield' is:
001,Surname1,Shaun,18/09/86,Sheffield,012345,Male,shaun@shaun.com001,Surname1,Shaun,18/09/86,Sheffield,012345,Male,shaun@shaun.com001,Surname1,Shaun,18/09/86,Sheffield,012345,Male,shaun@shaun.com001,Surname1,Shaun,18/09/86,Sheffield,012345,Male,shaun@shaun.com

Comment: why are both `input` and `raw_input` used? BTW, use `.find` instead of `index` and avoid scanning twice

Comment: maybe `if city_input in City:` should be `if city_input in row:` ?

Comment: @Pynchia Doing the above outputs the following:
001,Surname1,Shaun,18/09/86,Sheffield,012345,Male,shaun@shaun.com
001,Surname1,Shaun,18/09/86,Sheffield,012345,Male,shaun@shaun.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database is in a csv file, I like to use pandas something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('citydat.csv', header=None, 
     names=['code','sur','name','date','city','post','sex','email'])
df.set_index('code', inplace=True, drop=True)
cities = df.city.unique()
while True:
    city = input('enter city: ').title()
    if city in cities:
        print(df[df.city==city])
    elif city == '':
        break
    else:
        print(city,'not in database')
```

Running it looks like this:

```
enter city: new york
New York not in database
enter city: sheffield
          sur   name      date       city   post   sex            email
code                                                                    
1     Surname1  Shaun  18/09/86  Sheffield  12345  Male  shaun@shaun.com
4     Surname4  Bryan  01/01/01  Sheffield  12345  Male   Bryan@deaf.com
enter city:
```

EDIT: if you don't have pandas you can do something like this using the csv module, which should be in your python distribution.

```
import csv
with open('citydat.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
while True:
    city = input('enter city: ').title()
    if city == '':
        break
    lines = [line for line in reader if line[4]==city] # city name is index 4
    if lines == []:
        print(city,'not in database')
    else:
        for line in lines:
            print(line)


enter city: new york
New York not in database
enter city: sheffield
['001', 'Surname1', 'Shaun', '18/09/86', 'Sheffield', '012345', 'Male', 'shaun@shaun.com']
['004', 'Surname4', 'Bryan', '01/01/01', 'Sheffield', '012345', 'Male', 'Bryan@deaf.com']
enter city: boston
Boston not in database
enter city:
```

If you don't have the csv module, or don't want to use it for some reason(?) then you can use the same logic but open the file as text and do some further processing on the lines.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not have access to the pandas library on the system I'm using. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Great, thank you for the edit. This has worked a charm. Thanks @Steve Misuta